# React page doesn't display properly after updating or creating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks

I have simple note app based on Django+Rest+React. It contains list of notes page (`NotesListPage.js`) and note pages (`NotePage.js`). List of notes page contains short previews, titles and links to note pages. The NotePage, in addition to the entire content, contains delete and update functionality. It works, but sometimes (~50%) to see updates on NotesListPage it needs hard refresh or step back to NotePage and come back to list of notes again.

When I look at the sequence of execution of functions in the console, everything goes in the correct order. First, updating the note, then reloading the data.

How can this be fixed?

**NotesListPage.js**

```
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem'
import AddButton from '../components/AddButton'

const NotesListPage = () => {

    let [notes, setNotes] = useState([])

    let getNotes = async () => {
        let response = await fetch('/api/notes/')
        let data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        setNotes(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getNotes().then(() => {console.log('NotesList useEffect getNote')})
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="notes">
            <div className="notes-list">
                {notes.map((note, index) => (
                    <ListItem key={index} note={note} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <AddButton />
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotesListPage
```

**NotePage.js**

```
import { ReactComponent as ArrowLeft } from '../assets/arrow-left.svg'

const NotePage = ({ match, history }) => {

    let noteId = match.params.id
    let [note, setNote] = useState(null)

    let getNote = async () => {
        if (noteId === 'new') return

        let response = await fetch(`/api/notes/${noteId}/`)
        let data = await response.json()
        setNote(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getNote().then(() => {console.log('NotePage useEffect getNote')})
    }, [noteId])

    let createNote = async () => {
        await fetch(`/api/notes/`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(note)
        })
    }
    
    let updateNote = async () => {
        await fetch(`/api/notes/${noteId}/`, {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(note)
        })
    }
    
    let deleteNote = async () => {
        await fetch(`/api/notes/${noteId}/`, {
            method: 'DELETE',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        history.push('/')
    }

    let handleSubmit = () => {
        console.log('NOTE:', note)
        if (noteId !== 'new' && note.body === '') {
            deleteNote().then(() => {console.log('deleteNote')})
        } else if (noteId !== 'new') {
            updateNote().then(() => {console.log('updateNote')})
        } else if (noteId === 'new' && note.body !== null) {
            createNote().then(() => {console.log('createNote')})
        }
        history.push('/')
    }

    let handleChange = (value) => {
        setNote(note => ({ ...note, 'body': value }))
        console.log('Handle Change:', note)
    }

    return (
        <div className="note" >
            <div className="note-header">
                <h3>
                    <ArrowLeft onClick={handleSubmit} />
                </h3>
                {noteId !== 'new' ? (
                    <button onClick={deleteNote}>Delete</button>
                ) : (
                    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Done</button>
                )}

            </div>
            <textarea onChange={(e) => { handleChange(e.target.value) }} value={note?.body}></textarea>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotePage
```

**ListItem.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

let getTime = (note) => {
    return new Date(note.updated).toLocaleDateString()
}

let getTitle = (note) => {

    let title = note.body.split('\n')[0]
    if (title.length > 45) {
        return title.slice(0, 45)
    }
    return title
}

let getContent = (note) => {
    let title = getTitle(note)
    let content = note.body.replaceAll('\n', ' ')
    content = content.replaceAll(title, '')

    if (content.length > 45) {
        return content.slice(0, 45) + '...'
    } else {
        return content
    }
}

const ListItem = ({ note }) => {
    return (
        <Link to={`/note/${note.id}`}>
            <div className="notes-list-item" >
                <h3>{getTitle(note)}</h3>
                <p><span>{getTime(note)}</span>{getContent(note)}</p>
            </div>

        </Link>
    )
}

export default ListItem
```

**App.js**

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";


import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header'
import NotesListPage from './pages/NotesListPage'
import NotePage from './pages/NotePage'

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container dark">
        <div className="app">
          <Header title="Note List" />
          <Route path="/" exact component={NotesListPage} />
          <Route path="/note/:id" component={NotePage} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: So even `NotesList useEffect getNote` is called, the data is on refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added **async** and **await** to **handleSubmit** in **NotePage.js** and and it looks like it fixed the problem.

```
let handleSubmit = async () => {
        console.log('NOTE:', note)
        if (noteId !== 'new' && note.body === '') {
            deleteNote().then(() => {console.log('deleteNote')})
        } else if (noteId !== 'new') {
            await updateNote().then(() => {console.log('updateNote')})
        } else if (noteId === 'new' && note.body !== null) {
            await createNote().then(() => {console.log('createNote')})
        }
        history.push('/')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that the router is trying to be smart and it does not refetch the notes on the navigation back.

That could be solved by moving the `let [notes, setNotes] = useState([])` to the app, and you could then avoid fetching the individual notes as well (on the premise they don't fetch some addition info)